# コードブロックへの行番号の表示

Tags: 機能の要求

要望です。

コードブロックとしてマークアップされたブロックに行番号が表示されるとうれしいです。

Comment: Stack Exchange Meta 上の関連投稿です: ["Why are there no line numbers in the code listings?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7119/341401)

Comment: Stack Overflow Meta 上の関連投稿です: ["Why is there no line numbering in code sections?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/5989200)

Answer (score 3):

以下のような形であれば、実装されても良いと思います。

- デフォルトでは無効になる。既存の投稿で言及されている行数とコードブロックでの行数が食い違う可能性があるためです。たとえばプログラムの断片をペーストした場合、エラーメッセージの行数とコードブロックの行数が現れるためややこしいことになります。また、コードブロックの中身が編集されて改行が挟まった場合、行数が変わってしまうという小さな問題もあります (これは今でもそうかも?)。

  - 有効にするための方法は、[language コメント](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/341401)のようにコードブロックの前に特殊なコメントを挟む形が良いと思います。
- 文字列選択するときに行番号は選択されない。コードをコピー＆ペーストする方に易しい設計にしたいです。

Comment: フォーマットを崩してしまう、の意味がわかりません。

Comment: 質問に記入されたコードとエラーメッセージの行が一致しない場合があるのは行番号の表示の有無にかかわらず変わらないので、今以上にややこしくなることはありません。

Comment: @suzukis 「フォーマットを崩してしまう」の部分を書き換えました。

Comment: @suzukis 今以上にややこしくなるかについて：　ご指摘ありがとうございます。そうしてみると、そもそも行数を用いてコードの位置を指定すること自体がややこしいのかもしれません。エラーメッセージで行数が出てきている場合は仕方が無いですが、行番号による指定を助長するような変更はするべきではないのかもしれないと今思えてきました。もう少し考えてみます。

Comment: 考えた結果、行番号を使うと長期的には分かりにくさを生みやすいのではないかと思えてきました。しかし同時に、行番号があった方が分かりやすい場面もあるだろうと考え、1つの選択肢としてこのような機能がある分には良いだろうとも思えてきたので、現状の意見をそのまま主張します。オプションとして実装されることを歓迎します。